# Is there a replay cache in Kerberos 4?

Tags: kerberos

Does Kerberos version 4 support replay cache like in V5 - a cache that prevents replay attacks which occur **within** the clock skew, so the TGS knows a duplicate packet has arrived ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The replay cache was introduced in V5 and is new in V5.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Just so you know, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green tick below the up/down voting buttons.

Comment: Can you supplement your answer with a source for this knowledge?